# Images are not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm using [this](https://templated.co/ion) template, and when I upload it to my domain just to test it, the images are not showing, as you can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJdjv.png). The website should look like the demo.
You can download the template to your self, I would have liked to make a pastebin for you guys, but I don't have 10 reputation.

So what you guys think is the problem?

Comment: Your missing more than just the images, also css seems to be missing

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Are you uploading the images and assets folders to your website?  They should be in the same folder as your HTML files.

Comment: seems like its fixed?

Comment: Please post the code here, don't make us have to go to another page

Answer (score 1):

While it is the best to correct `url("../images/banner.jpg")` of `#banner`, if you still only want the background image, put `background-image: url("http://templated.co/items/demos/ion/images/banner.jpg");`